# why in bip32 entropy's max size is 512 bit , but bip39 is 256 bit?

Tags: bitcoin

from bip 32 https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0032.mediawiki

> Generate a seed byte sequence S of a chosen length (between 128 and 512 bits; 256 bits is advised) from a (P)RNG.

max entropy can be 512bit

from bip 39 https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0039.mediawiki

> The allowed size of ENT is 128-256 bits.

max entropy can only be 256bit(use 24 words).

so why we cant use 48 word create a 512bit entropy under bip39?